# spring integration leader election revoking leadership with jdbc lock registry when sending message to control bus

Tags: spring-boot, spring-integration

I have build this sample POC where I would like to start spring integration jdbc inbound channel adapter when leader is elected. I do see that when i add the code which send control bus message to start jdbc inbound channel adapter than it is immediately revoking the leadership, so running in a state where i don't have any active leader running. If I comment out the code which send message to control bus then I always have one leader running in the cluster.

Here is the complete POC code

[Leader election poc](https://github.com/pritspatel/leader-election-demo)

This is what I am doing in my custom candidate object

```
@Override
public void onGranted(Context context) {
    super.onGranted(context);
    System.out.println("*** Leadership granted ***");
    System.out.println("STARTING JDBC POLLER");
    Message<String> startMsg = MessageBuilder.withPayload("@jdbcPoller.start()").build();
    systemMessageChannel.send(startMsg);
    System.out.println("STARTUP MESSAGE SENT");

}

 @Override
public void onRevoked(Context context) {

    System.out.println("*** Leadership revoked ***");
    System.out.println("STOPPING JDBC POLLER");
    Message<String> stringMessage = MessageBuilder.withPayload("@jdbcPoller.stop()").build();
    systemMessageChannel.send(stringMessage);
    System.out.println("SHUTDOWN MESSAGE SENT");
    super.onRevoked(context);
}
```

Can someone please tell me what is wrong with this code ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like your problem is here:

```
@Bean
public LockRegistryLeaderInitiator leaderInitiator(LockRegistry lockRegistry) {
    return new LockRegistryLeaderInitiator(lockRegistry, new LeaderCandidate());
}
```

You see how you create your `LeaderCandidate` as an in-line object. Since this is supposed to be involved in the dependency injection, you must declare it as a bean:

```
@Bean
public LockRegistryLeaderInitiator leaderInitiator(LockRegistry lockRegistry) {
    return new LockRegistryLeaderInitiator(lockRegistry, leaderCandidate());
}

@Bean
public Candidate leaderCandidate() {
    return new LeaderCandidate();
}
```

Also consider do not drop tables when start a new instance of your application.

Comment: Thanks a lot Artem. That solved the problem. And yes, I am not going to recreate table everytime instance is started.